# When to use exceptions and optionals in Swift error handling?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I'm trying to understand Swift error handling better, but I can't find a specific answer to this question online. I have an application that uses optionals a lot to do error handling. For example, here's a snippet of code from my app:

```swift
if let winnerName = gameApiResponse.winner {
    guard let gameFromApi = GameFromApi(id: gameApiResponse.id, contestantsNames: gameApiResponse.contestants, winnerName: winnerName, confidence: 50, conferencesNames: conferenceNamesInGame, week: gameApiResponse.week) else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap new game object in loadGames(gameApiResponses:) in DataModelManager", type: .debug)
        return GameFromApi()
    }
    return gameFromApi
} else {
    guard let gameFromApi = GameFromApi(id: gameApiResponse.id, contestantsNames: gameApiResponse.contestants, winnerName: nil, confidence: 50, conferencesNames: conferenceNamesInGame, week: gameApiResponse.week) else {
        os_log("Could not unwrap new game object in loadGames(gameApiResponses:) in DataModelManager", type: .debug)
        return GameFromApi()
    }
    return gameFromApi
}
```

GameFromApi is a class that has a failable initializer and a default, non-failable initializer (with no parameters). If the regular initializer fails, I call the default initializer and just give this function back a "blank" GameFromApi object that has default values. But I'm mostly using this default initializer to indicate that something went wrong, which feels bad. Plus, I feel like I'm overusing optionals to do error handling in cases when the reason for the failure could be many different things.

What's the litmus test for when to use optionals to indicate an error, and when to use exceptions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optionals vs Throwing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31077613/1187415)

Comment: Side note: In Swift it is called throwing an “error,” not an “exception.”

Comment: @MartinR To add to that, the difference isn't pedantic. Swift doesn't have stack unwinding for exception handling. Error throwing is syntactic sugar for a tuple return

Comment: Indeed: From https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ErrorHandling.rst: We're intentionally not using the term "exception handling" ... Throwing an error provides similar performance to allocating an error and returning it -- it isn't an expensive, table-based stack unwinding process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw errors whenever details of the error are available, and they could be used in some way to recover the error.

For example, opening a file on the filesystem might fail because of an incorrect path, a permission error, or the file being the wrong type (e.g. a folder). A thrown error might include this information, but it won't really help, because there wouldn't be much your application could do with that information to recover from the error.

In your case, I think optionals are a good choice. However, you shouldn't repeat yourself:

```
guard let gameFromApi = GameFromApi(
    id: gameApiResponse.id,
    contestantsNames: gameApiResponse.contestants,
    winnerName: gameApiResponse.winner,
    confidence: 50,
    conferencesNames: conferenceNamesInGame,
    week: gameApiResponse.week
) else {
    os_log("Could not unwrap new game object in loadGames(gameApiResponses:) in DataModelManager", type: .debug)
    return GameFromApi()
}
return gameFromApi
```